# Как поставить метку google maps чтобы точка метки располагалась слева(есть скриншот)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api, google-maps

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно вот так расположить метку, но по классике точка находится в нижней части метки.Как изменить ее так, чтобы она была слева?

Answer (score 1):

Задайте принудительно `anchor`:

```
anchor: new google.maps.Point(-30, 32) //вот здесь в пикселях вы можете задавать отклонение маркера сейчас на 30px отклонен вправо и на 32px вверх
```

Например:

```js
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 55.751189,
    lng: 37.629043
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  setMarkers(map);
}

var points = [
  ['Point1', 55.751189, 37.629043, 1]
];

function setMarkers(map) {
  var image = {
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(-30, 32) //вот здесь в пикселях вы можете задавать отклонение маркера сейчас на 30px отклонен вправо и на 32px вверх
  };
  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var point = points[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: point[1],
        lng: point[2]
      },
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      shape: shape,
      title: point[0],
      zIndex: point[3]
    });
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id=map></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=initMap">
</script>
```